# Facebook Messenger Bot: Session Variables

Tags: php, bots, facebook-messenger

I am using PHP to write the bot. I am storing selected items in a session variable in my `webhooks` file. Thing is that on next request of hooks it does not show Session data and returns empty.

Answer (score 6):

Facebook doesn't keep a session open with your webhook. You have to think about it as a "session per request" scope. In other words, you have to implement a simple in-memory structure to store conversation data -- key-value store recommended, using the sender id as the key. You could also use [redis](http://redis.io/) for this task.